# An irrelevant NullPointerException during serialization

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception

I use serialization for saving the current state of my model to a file and load it maybe some minutes later. My application has nothing that deals JPA or similar technologies. It's a completely JavaSE desktop Swing Application.
Serialization works quite well. Only I encountered that after the serialization the DnD feature that I have defined for a JList to another one stops to function(The DnD feature is defined by me and isn't a default one). I don't serialize the GUI. I just serialize and save the models. The GUI is created every time the program is run.

But once upon a time I discovered that the following exception occurs and the model isn't serialized. This exception happened only once. I could save the serialized model before that.(I note that no change happened in the code) It doesn't have a clue in my code. The line of the code where this exception is thrown is:

```
out.writeObject(galMachine);
```

I know that the error is so obscure but I appreciate any clue. Thanks!

Btw, the galMachine isn't null. The program works well so all its members have been initialized correctly!

**Note: This exception can happen only when I have loaded a serialized instance to the program and not when it has created all its objects itself.**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI.installDefaults(MetalScrollBarUI.java:90)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.installUI(BasicScrollBarUI.java:168)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.writeObject(JScrollBar.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1687)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:478)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3681)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1687)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:478)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3681)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at View.AppJFrame.saveMenuItemActionPerformed(AppJFrame.java:430)
    at View.AppJFrame.access$500(AppJFrame.java:51)
    at View.AppJFrame$4.actionPerformed(AppJFrame.java:307)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I'm using Java 1.7 with a GUI mostly created with Netbeans 7.2 GUI builder. I've got no Netbeans specific feature in the application and the first line refers to the first line of the following method in the Java codes:

```
protected void installDefaults() {
    scrollBarWidth = ((Integer)(UIManager.get( "ScrollBar.width" ))).intValue();
    super.installDefaults();
    bumps = new MetalBumps( 10, 10, thumbHighlightColor, thumbShadow, thumbColor );
}
```

I note again that I have no interest to save the GUI and I have no reference in my model(galMachine) to any GUI object. All important things directly for the GUI are two `AbstractListModel` objects that have no reference to their `JList` components. I only serialize the `galMachine`.

---

I discovered that a similar exception could occur also on dragDrop inside the overriden `importData` method. It occurs at the first line after try

```
try {
    
    Object obj = ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(TransferableProductJob.PRODUCTJOB_DATA_FLAVOR);
    if(obj instanceof ProductJob){
        
        ProductJob pj = (ProductJob) obj;
        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation) ts.getDropLocation();
        int idx = dl.getIndex();
        StoreTank tank = ((StoreTank) jl.getModel().getElementAt(idx));
        if(tank.getCurrentJobStage() != null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\"" + tank.getDescription() + "\" è occupato.");
            return false;
        }
        tank.setReserved(true);
            tank.setReserved(false);
            return false;
        int initialTankNumber = tank.getNumber();
        pj.importToStroreTank(initialTankNumber);
        galvanicMachine.addJob(pj);
        pj.start();
    }
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WaitingListJPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WaitingListJPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (Exception ex ){
    Logger.getLogger(WaitingListJPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI.installDefaults(MetalScrollBarUI.java:90)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.installUI(BasicScrollBarUI.java:168)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.writeObject(JScrollBar.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1687)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:478)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1687)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:478)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferData(TransferableProxy.java:83)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferData(DropTargetContext.java:376)
    at View.panels.WaitingListJPanel$JListTransferHandler.importData(WaitingListJPanel.java:240)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1536)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:450)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1274)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:537)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:851)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:775)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4716)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4566)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4417)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

---

I searched the Internet and I discovered such this error has happened and announced as a bug only once before and has been rejected as a bug. This is [the bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4417287). But it can't be in my code because I don't try to initialize two `JScrollPane` in two threads simultaneously but I hope that it will help for suggesting a solution.

Comment: We're going to need more code than this to figure out your exception.

Comment: @crush Ja! There are around 20,000 lines of code but can you guide please which part of it can be useful?

Comment: Let's start with the code referenced by the stack trace.

Comment: @crush I have brought that line of code! It is out.writeObject(galMachine); and enough ant it's clear which kind of object out is(ObjectOutputStream). I have no overriden read/writeObject and it is the only line in my whole program that writes the model to a serialized file.

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Try to track down what MetalScrollBarUI.java:90 does (the first line of your stacktrace). Please create an example that always produces the error, and you might get better help. http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @Atreys I added more info the question. I try to make a sscce.org that would generate the same error however it doesn't look trivial.

Comment: @Atreys I found it completely impossible to reproduce the error in an independent program but I could find where that JScrollPane could be! It is the parent of the JList the one that netbeans adds by default. It could be interesting that in the main program I never serialize any GUI object and I do only with model classes that have no reference to the View classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a quite painful remedy. It should be a bug in Java. When I change the lookAndFeel from nimbus to the system default or metal the problem disappears. So it is a bug in Java! :(

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
```