# Issue with MetalScrollBarUI class in Java

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to set the UI of my scroll bar in NetBeans to a MetalScrollBarUI, but when I use this code:

```
JScrollBar jsb = jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar();
ScrollBarUI sbui = new MetalScrollBarUI();
jsb.setUI(sbui); // this is NewJFrame.java:35
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI.installDefaults(MetalScrollBarUI.java:90)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.installUI(BasicScrollBarUI.java:168)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setUI(JScrollBar.java:207)
at NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:35)
at NewJFrame$3.run(NewJFrame.java:176)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

This person had a similar issue, but his fix only created more errors for me. Does anyone know what is wrong here? [An irrelevant NullPointerException during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957393/an-irrelevant-nullpointerexception-during-serialization)

Comment: The `MetalScrollBarUI` is relying a property from the `UIManager` which is likely not set, as it's not supported by the currently installed look and feel ... `scrollBarWidth = ((Integer)(UIManager.get( "ScrollBar.width" ))).intValue();`...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just had to create a custom JFrame form template that switched the Nimbus look and feel for Metal.